# Test account in apple requests confirmation

Tags: iphone, deployment, app-store

I have created test accounts for my iPhone application in itunesconnect.apple.com
and i could able to use this to test my in app purchase product.

But after a while when i click "Buy" option it shows a prompt like below

[image]

I clicked continue to review my info and could able to receive email for test account,
and i clicked to review it. But after that too i get the same error.

Please suggest.

Comment: I'm getting the same error as well. Yesterday it worked fine, but today it appears Apple has broken something. Other users are reporting this as well: https://discussions.apple.com/message/22959239#22959239

Comment: oh.. thanks for letting me know.. i thought its a problem with the account created..

Answer (score 1):

Finally got my app to generate receipts again. I had to create a new test account in iTunesConnect and set the iTunes store to USA.

Comment: +1 for letting me know that this is a common problem..
still i cannot create a valid account though..